# Set list of tables and list of figures as section in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want the list of figures and the list of tables to appear in my table of contents as sections instead of as chapters. A bit like the elements right above (from summary to acronyms)

A quick reminder that I used

> \listoftables
>
> \listoffigures

To automatically generate the list of tables and figures

I also used

> \section*{Summary}
> \label{sec:summary}
> \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:summary}}

To create and and the sections to the table of contents

[image: Table of contents]

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter}{\section}{}{}` and similarly for `\listoftables`

Comment: It's not working

Comment: I think that I'll have to use `\renewcommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion using package `tocbasic`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown,totoc}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\begin{table}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}%
  \caption{A figure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: `tocbasic` can not be used together with package `tocloft` or `titletoc`.

Comment: Thank you problem solved

Comment: That is a complete solution, since it changes not only the toc entries to section, but also changes pagestyle (e.g. chapter may break pages, whereas section does not) and variables (e.g. section/chapter in the headings) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need to change any pre-existing code.

```
% loftoc.tex  SE 600162
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\addcontentsline` is basic LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that `\listoffigures` automatically adds the content line to the table of content

Comment: I get the list of figures repeated twice in the table of contents: one being showed as section and one being shown as chapter

Comment: @PenielAdounkpe As you have not bothered to show what documentclass you are using then why should I bother to try and help? My solution works for the `report`, and `book` classes. With a minor adjustment, use `listoffigures*` it works for the `memoir` class.