# Extract summary out of table of contents (toc)

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to get a summary out of toc. The summary should only show chapters and sections. I used the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tableofcontentssummary}{%
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=1\relax% usually show part, chapter and section only
    \@fileswfalse
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Summary}%
    \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\section*{Summary}
\markboth{}{SUMMARY}
\label{sec:summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:summary}}

\tableofcontentssummary
```

This should work but I am getting issues with the functions I previously added to the toc. They also apply themselves to the summary. I want to remove >\renewcommand and and >\addtocontents{toc}.

They were implemented to set the table of contents name, to add a newpage between toc title and contents and to set header.

> \renewcommand*\tableofcontents{\listoftoc[{Table of Contents}]{toc}}
>
> \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage \markboth{}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

Here is what I get.

[image: Page ii]
[image: Page iii]
[image: Page iv]

Comment: Please provide a complete (compilable) code that includes `documentclass` and the *relevant* `packages`. This is called MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Otherwise, there is a big risk that there are misunderstandings and wrong assumptions.

Comment: If you can use any class, `memoir` could be a good choice for you. Take a look at section 9.2.5 of the manual. In fact its table of contents is an example of what I believe you want

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}`

Comment: The rest of my includes is pretty long (150 lines). It does not fit in the comment

Comment: For future reference, don't post code or updates in comments.  [edit] it into the post itself.  And a MWE is almost never 150 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming package `tocbasic` is already in use (`\listoftoc` is a `tocbasic` macro):

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand*{\originaltableofcontents}{\listoftoc[\contentsname]{toc}}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown,totoc}
\BeforeTOCHead{\clearpage}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\ExecuteDoHook{aftertochead/toc}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tableofcontentssummary}{%
  \begingroup
    \value{tocdepth}=1\relax% usually show part, chapter and section only
    \@fileswfalse
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Summary}%
    \setuptoc{toc}{leveldown,totoc}%
    \originaltableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
  \AddtoOneTimeDoHook{aftertochead/toc}{\maintocsetup}%
  \setuptoc{toc}{totoc}%
  \originaltableofcontents
}
\newcommand*\maintocsetup[1]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\markboth{}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}%
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontentssummary
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\begin{table}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}%
  \caption{A figure}%
\end{figure}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A dirty trick: First compile twice  the document with the usual `\tableofcontents`, then remove it and use the .toc file directly as many times as you want.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
% \tableofcontents
\section*{Default ToC}
\input{\jobname.toc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\section*{ToC Summary}
\input{\jobname.toc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\section*{Full ToC}
\input{\jobname.toc}
\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If manually comment one line after first compilation is too much work, you can do also automatically:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\IfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{%
\chapter{Contents}%
\input{\jobname.toc}%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}%
\chapter{ToC Summary}
\input{\jobname.toc}}%
{\tableofcontents%
\marginpar{\huge Compile\\ again!}}
\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Again you have not provided an MWE that shows the `\documentclass`. The answers to yourprevious question [Set list of tables and list of figures as section in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600162) showed two MWEs but you seem to have taken no notice of what they looked like. --- GOM

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` classes) then this simply provides for multiple ToCs. The following is an MWE of 30 lines showing this.

```
% shorttocprob.tex SE 600373
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% The short ToC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % chapters and sections
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Short ToC}
\tableofcontents* % this does not add Contents to the ToC

% The regular ToC
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % chapters to subsections
%\tableofcontents  % this adds Contents to the ToC
\tableofcontents* % this does not add Contents to the ToC

\mainmatter
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}  % number subsections

\chapter{A chapter}
Text.
\section{A section}
Text.
\subsection{A subsection}
Text.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]