# Table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am looking for solution to my problem :

1. I want the table of contents to display the titles (Tables des matières, liste des figures et listes des tableaux) with dots.
2. Also, in the "NOTATIONS" section I want the table of ratings to be displayed on the same page as the title.
3. The header of the "Notations" section is not displayed.  [image]

[image]

```
 %%%%%%%%% Table des matières   %%%%%%%
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}     % Pas besoin de trop détailler le sommaire ici (chapitres/sections)
            \dominitoc                           % Génération des mini-toc  \pagenumbering{arabic}
            \tableofcontents
        % Liste des figures
            \renewcommand*\listfigurename{Liste des figures}
            \listoffigures
        % Liste des tableaux
            \listoftables
    % Notation

\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Notations}

\begin{table}[!h]
\label{Notations}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l l c }
\toprule
\textbf {Notation} & \textbf {Désignation} & \textbf {Unité}  \\ \\ 
$\eta$& Facteur de substitution surfacique & $[\%]$  \\ 
$A_L$ & Section chargée du sol & $[{mm}^2]$ \\
$A$ & Section totale du sol  & $[{mm}^2]$ \\ 
$A_c$  & Section de la colonne & $[{mm}^2]$ \\  
$A_{cont}$ & Surface de contact sol-colonne (interface) & $[{mm}^2]$ \\
$D_c$ & Diamètre de la colonne  & $[mm]$ \\ 
$D_0$ & Diamètre du moule  & $[mm]$ \\ 
$G_{max}$ & Plus gros diamètre de grain du ballast & $[mm]$\\
$d_{max}$ & Plus gros diamètre de grain du sol &$[mm]$\\
$H_0$ & Hauteur du moule & $[mm]$ \\
$H_{couche}$ & Hauteur de couche  & $[mm]$\\
$L_0$ & Longueur du moule  & $[mm]$ \\
$C_c$ & Coefficient de courbure & $[-]$ \\
$C_u$ & Coefficient d'uniformité & $[-] $\\
$s$ & Tassement mesuré & $[mm]$ \\
$S$ & Espacement entre  colonnes & $[mm]$ \\
$k$ & Indice de gonfelement & $[-]$ \\
$n$ & Rapport de cencentration de la contrainte verticale & $[-]$ \\
$d_e$ & Diamètre d'influence d'une colonne & $[mm]$ \\
$\rho^{*}$ &  Masse volumique spécifique & $[kg\diagup {m^3}]$ \\
$\rho_d$ & Masse volumique sèche & $[kg\diagup {m^3}]$ \\
$e$ &  Indice des vides &$ [-]$ \\
$w$ & Teneur en eau initiale & $[\%]$ \\
$w_L$ & Limite de liquidité & $[\%]$ \\
$\sigma_p$ & Contrainte de préconsolidation & $[kPa]$\\
$c_u$ & Cohésionn non drainée & $[kPa]$ \\
$\phi$ & Angle de frottement & $[^\circ]$ \\
$\sigma$ & Contrainte totale appliquée &$ [kPa]$ \\
$\sigma_s$ & La contrainte verticale appliquée sur le sol & $[kPa]$ \\
$\epsilon$ & Déformation axiale & $[\%]$ \\
$\nu$ & Coefficient de Poisson & $[-] $\\
$E_s$ & Module oedométrique  & $[kPa]$  \\
$E_{oed}$ & Module oedométrique  & $[kPa]$  \\
$E_{c}$ & Module d'Younng de la colonne & $[kPa]$  \\
$E_{sr}^{hom}$ & Module d'Younng homogénéisé & $[kPa]$  \\
$E_{sr}^{exp}$ & Module d'Younng mesuré & $[kPa]$ \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
%\caption{}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you are doing that we can compile. What is the class you are using? How do you get the LoF listed in the ToC? Is your Notations table too long?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600162/set-list-of-tables-and-list-of-figures-as-section-in-table-of-contents?r=SearchResults&s=2|39.5295

Comment: Tank you for your interesting, `documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright]{report}
\input{Preambule}  % Liste des packages et de leurs options
\input{CommandesPerso} % Commandes et environnements perso''"é(§è!çà)`

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright]{report}
\input{Preambule}  % Liste des packages et de leurs options
\input{CommandesPerso} % Commandes et environnements perso

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%      Liste des fichiers à compiler     %

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph {subsubsection}}
\setcounter{mtc}{4} 



\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\includepdf{Pagedegarde} 

 \cleardoublepage
  
 \pagenumbering{roman} 
  
%        Contenu du document        %


\section*{Dédicace}

\begin{fquote}
\begin{center}`